# Camera Calibration Error Estimation in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

Well, after estimating the initial guess of camera parameters using closed form, how can we use the CvLevMarq Class to implement non-linear least squares algorithm to estimate the errors of the parameters obtained from the closed form.